# The download only has the contents of the answers

Tags: xml, winforms

I have a method for loading responses, but it loads everything, even empty textboxes,
and I need exactly those that only have content

```
 private void LoadAnswers()
    {
        var currentQuestion = _bsQuestions.Current as Question;
        var bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = currentQuestion.Answers;

        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        if (currentQuestion.Type == QuestionType.SingleSelect )
        {
            uc = new UserControlSingle(bs);
            label4.Text = $"select 1 of { bs.Count} the answers";
        }
        else
        {
            uc = new UserControlMulti(bs);
            label4.Text = $"select several of { bs.Count} the answers";
        }
        _panel.Controls.Clear();
        _panel.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

UserControlMulti

```
 public partial class UserControlMulti : UserControl
{
    private readonly BindingSource _bs;

    public UserControlMulti(BindingSource bindingSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _bs = bindingSource ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingSource));
        SetBindings();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _bs.Count; i++)
        {
            //textboxes
            var textBox = _panelMulti.Controls
                .OfType<TextBox>().First(t => t.Name.EndsWith((i + 1).ToString()));
            textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bs[i],
           nameof(Answer.Value), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

            //checkboxes

            var checkbox = _panelMulti.Controls
                .OfType<CheckBox>().First(t => t.Name.EndsWith((i + 1).ToString()));
            checkbox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _bs[i], nameof(Answer.IsCorrect));


        }
    }
}
```

UserControlSingle identical

In short, me need to load all the textbox except empty well, how to load the checkbox which should be the same as the textbox in number

Comment: Why not just put a check for textBox.text == string.empty before adding it to the databindings and continue if it is?

Comment: @Mac1ure If you are not difficult can you show an example?